# StorageClient 1.7 library inside SDK 2.3. Will it be supported?

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, storage

I noticed that inside SDK 2.3 we have Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll library with version 1.7. Why SDK uses so old library and will it be supported after August 1. According to this article we have this information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn744252.aspx

So I wonder will it stop working or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for long. Version 1.7 of the library targets an older version of REST API which is set to retire on August 1st 2015. Azure Storage Team has posted a blog about this which you can read here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/05/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal.aspx.